# Does Spring's Environment Abstraction use PropertyEditors?

Tags: java, spring

My google-fu is failing me on this one.

I'm using Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE with java configuration. What I'm trying to do is [register a custom property editor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) to convert from a String to a Map.

So I have a Java Configuration class that registers the appropriate BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
@Bean
public static CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer(){
    CustomEditorConfigurer configurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    Map<Class<?>, Class<? extends PropertyEditor>> customEditors = new HashMap<>();
    customEditors.put(Map.class, DelimitedStringToMapPropertyEditor.class);
    configurer.setCustomEditors(customEditors);


    return configurer;
}
```

In the same configuration class I am also injecting the `Environment`

```
@Resource
private Environment environment;
```

However, when I try to get the String property (which is also unfortunately named `environment`) that I want converted to a map, I get an exception.

```
environment.getProperty("environment", Map.class, Collections.EMPTY_MAP)
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value [VAR=hello] from source type [String] to target type [Map]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:94)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:65)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.getProperty(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:546)
```

**BUT** if I inject the property directly using the `@Value` annotation, it works just fine.

```
@Value("${environment}")
private Map<String, String> shellEnvironment;
```

So, what gives? Does the `Environment` object not take into account registered property editors? Do I need to create a custom [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)? Isn't the `Environment` abstraction the latest and greatest way to resolve properties that come from anywhere?

Comment: Correct it is a way to resolve properties it isn't a way to convert properties. When using the `@Value` 2 things happen, first the property is resolved, second conversion is attempted (only basic conversion String to numbers/booleans is done through plain java not converters/editors.). You only do the resolution part not the conversion part.

Comment: @M.Deinum So if I want to resolve and convert, I have to use `@Value`?

Comment: Yes, or do conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**; the Environment abstraction does not use registered Property Editors. It only resolves properties (and does basic Type Conversion).

---

Thanks to the comments from @M. Deinum I was able to come to a decent compromise.

> Correct it is a way to resolve properties it isn't a way to convert properties. When using the @Value 2 things happen, first the property is resolved, second conversion is attempted (only basic conversion String to numbers/booleans is done through plain java not converters/editors.). You only do the resolution part not the conversion part. – M. Deinum

You have to kind of read between the lines in the reference manual to come to this understanding.

The [Environment Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment) chapter states:

> The role of the Environment object with relation to properties is to provide the user with a convenient service interface for configuring property sources and **resolving properties from them**.

Notice it does not say anything about conversion/editors. (Although I did notice that it does actually handle simple [Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) because [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) inherits [PropertyResolver.getPropertyAsClass](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getPropertyAsClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-))

So I decided to combine the two methods and settled on this method of injecting my properties into my configuration class:

```
@Resource
private Environment environment;

@Value("#{environment['environment']?:{:}}")
private Map<String, String> shellEnvironment;
```